# Ng-view template loader not working on apache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I have this in app.js:

```
var myApp =
    angular
        .module('myApp', [ 'ngRoute' ])

        // configure our routes
        .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          $routeProvider
              .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/take.html',
                controller : 'myCtrl'
              })
              .when('/take', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/take.html',
                controller : 'myCtrl'
              })
              .when('/part',
                    {templateUrl : 'partials/part.html', controller : 'myCtrl'})
              .when('/program', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/program.html',
                controller : 'myCtrl'
              })
              .when(
                  '/forum',
                  {templateUrl : 'partials/forum.html', controller : 'myCtrl'})
              .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});

          $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

I have this in index.html:

```
...
<ng-view></ng-view>
...
  <!-- angularJS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

...
```

And my apache2.conf file is as follows:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
        Options Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>

# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

My .htaccess file contains this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(upload|upload_cover)\.php
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

For some reason muy templates wont load on the ng-view. Im using AngularJS over an apache server and index.html is working but the template zone appears blank. I have `<base href="/">` defined in my index.html. Ive been googling other similar questions and I used a similar .htaccess but this wont work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you make a small plunker with what you have. Also check your browser console to see if there's any errors.

Comment: Browser console insnt giving any errors. I also made a plunker: https://drive.google.com/a/uc3m.es/file/d/1IrowOvoTO_vo80Dag7xMdNiTM7Riylzh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I get your files and the problem is the module is defined on <head>...Put on html: "<html lang="es" ng-app="myApp">"